# On "drive something home"

Tags: phrase-usage, idioms, phrases

After developing an idea and expressing the reasons for that, I want to make an example for it. I want to use the "An example can drive this notion home" before the example. Is this expression right and formal? Am I using it in a right way?

> Some developments... . **An example can drive this notion home**. ... the example ... .

Answer (score 2):

When using a hammer to strike a nail we might make a few light taps to get it started and then drive it (fully) home with heavier blows. The nail becomes fixed as a result. We can figuratively drive an idea home (fix it) in someone's mind by some action or actions. So I would say yes, your example uses the expression correctly.

[Collins Dictionary:](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/drive-home)

> drive home
> in British English
> a. to cause to penetrate to the fullest
> extent
> b. to make clear by special emphasis

Answer (score 1):

> An example can drive this notion home

You definitely have the right idea but I would suggest that when we attempt to drive something home, it should perhaps be phrased more confidently or definitively, if that makes sense. Instead, consider this phrasing:

> An example will drive this point home.

I don't like the use of the words "can" and "notion" in this expression because the purpose of the expression is to take something relatively concrete (a point, not a notion) and attempt to *certify* it, in some sense. Be direct with your words and guide the reader with your confidence.

You could even shorthand it depending on how you styled the rest of the text and if you're willing to be conversational with the reader.

> An example will drive this home for us.